# Can't paint 2 of the same control on winForm

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm making a simple game in winform (tic-tac-toe), and I'm having some problem to paint block control.

Here is the class I made, that represent a block in the game (without game logic, is only UI).

```
public class UI_Block : Control
{
    private Rectangle block;
    private SIGNS sign;
    public  SIGNS Sign 
    {
        get {return sign;}
        set
        {
            if (sign == SIGNS.EMPTY)
                sign = value;
        } 
    }

    public UI_Block( ) {
        sign = SIGNS.EMPTY;
    }

    public void SetBlockOnBoard(int x, int y)
    {
        this.Location = new Point( x , y );
        this.Size = new Size(Parent.Width /3, Parent.Height / 3);

        block = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
    }

    public void DrawSign(Graphics g)
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);

        if (sign == SIGNS.O)
        {
            drawO(g,new Pen(Brushes.Black));
        }

        if (sign == SIGNS.X)
        {
            drawX(g, new Pen(Brushes.Red));
        }

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawSign(e.Graphics);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    //Draw X
    private void drawX(Graphics g, Pen myPen)
    {
        //draw first daignol
        Point daignolStart = new Point {  X = this.Location.X  ,  Y = this.Location.Y   };
        Point daignolEnd = new Point   {  X = this.Size.Width  ,  Y = this.Size.Height  };

        g.DrawLine(myPen, daignolStart, daignolEnd);

        //draw second daignol
        daignolStart = new Point {  X = Size.Width ,  Y = this.Location.Y  };
        daignolEnd = new Point   {  X = Location.X,   Y = Size.Height      };

        g.DrawLine(myPen, daignolEnd, daignolStart);
    }


    //Draw O
    private void drawO(Graphics g, Pen myPen)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(myPen, block);
    }

}
```

I added them both to the winForm class and to see how it looks like when I paint them:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UI.UI_Block block;
    UI.UI_Block blockX;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        block = new UI.UI_Block();
        blockX = new UI.UI_Block();
        Controls.Add(block);
        Controls.Add(blockX);

    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        block. SetBlockOnBoard(0, 0);
        blockX.SetBlockOnBoard(0, block.Height);

        block.Sign = SIGNS.X;
        blockX.Sign = SIGNS.O;

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //block.DrawSign(e.Graphics);
        //block.DrawSign(e.Graphics);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

}
```

I tried few things, like not using the `onPaint` event and I still get the same result.

Here what I see when I run it:

[image]
Any idea why I can't paint both of them?

Comment: Where are you calling the drawing methods? All I see is you putting the block down. It might work best to put that in the `set` for the `Sign` property.

Comment: i added both blocks to the winForm controls so the OnPaints Methods will be call every time i repaint the form (form.Invalidate). should i do it diffrently?

Comment: Step through your code and see if it is calling the OnPaint when the second control is added. You might have to add the `Graphics` from the form as a parameter to the UI_Block constructor. I haven't done much with Paint because of this reason. Could you just set up icons instead, or do you have to use Paint?

Comment: i added a MassageBox(this.Sign +"") to the OnPaint and they are both get called like i thogut. i tried to use the Graphic object from the form on both objects (and disabled the OnPaint) but i saw the same result. what did you mean by icons, did you mean images?

Comment: Yes. Add images to the project's resources, and when you set the `Sign`, use that to set the image to be displayed on the UI_Block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not drawing the contents of your control in it's visible area, so it is drawing fine but you can't see it.

Every control has it's own coordinate space (client coords), which starts at 0,0 regardless of where it is positioned within the parent control. You are placing the control in it's parent correctly by setting its Location, but then you are also using the Location to offset the graphics, so they are essentially offset twice.

(If you make your control bigger you'll be able to see the X    being drawn further down the screen)

To fix this, do all your drawing in the client coordinate space of your control, i.e. draw in the area (0, 0, width, height)

(P.S. You could just draw all 9 tiles in the parent control, which is a more efficient approach than creating 9 child controls. But what you are doing will work fine)